# Adjust Form Sheet When Keyboard Appears

Tags: ios, ipad

Apple has a preferred way to adjust UIScrollViews on the iPhone when the keyboard appears. I cannot seem to figure out how to adjust a UIScrollView inside of a form sheet to account for the keyboard appearance. I know that it can be done because the MFMailComposeViewController does this flawlessly. I cannot find out how to do this anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: If your form sheet is a view, you can listen for keyboard notifications and then animate you view up.

Answer (score 0):

Use this guide
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

you have to manage your view manually. : /